# Android Recycler view is not moving upwards when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In My application, I have used a recycler view and an EditText is placed just below this RecyclerView. When typing on Edit text, the view is not moving upwards. I have tried with  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"`, but no change.Is there any way to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did u use `adjustPan` ?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Thank you. adjust pan worked. But unable to scroll entire view upwards and downwards

Comment: Is your view in scrollView?

Comment: No. Can we add recyclerview inside scrollview

Comment: No. Its no need to add. RecycleView has its own orientation.

Comment: A button is placed below of EditText. When  using adjustPan  view is not scrolling to that button

Comment: how do you resolve it?